# Java Generic Class which Implements a Generic Interface

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Initially I wanted to create a generic way of deep copying objects which implement a 'X' interface. However, I did not want to write a copy list function for every class which implemented 'X'. Instead I created a generic Class which bounds it's generic with interface 'X'.

The problem lies that if class 'A' implements 'X' and contains sub-classes which (do)/(do not) implement 'X'. How do you stop sub-classes from inheriting from the 'A' implementation of 'X' and force their own implementation, without having to implement 'X for every sub-class.

I am pretty sure that this is impossible to do in java, due to inheritance, and generics.

Here is the implementation thus far, but I need a type cast which brings unsafe operations for sub-classes not inheriting interface 'X'.

```
import java.util.*;


public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window.
    System.out.println("Hello, World");

    List<Foo> l = new ArrayList<Foo>();
    List<Bar> b = new ArrayList<Bar>();
    List<Nar> n = new ArrayList<Nar>();

    GenericCopyClass<Foo> g = new GenericCopyClass<Foo>();
    GenericCopyClass<Bar> gb = new GenericCopyClass<Bar>();
    GenericCopyClass<Nar> gn = new GenericCopyClass<Nar>();


    l.add(new Foo());
    l.add(new Foo());
    l.add(new Foo());


    b.add(new Bar());
    b.add(new Bar());
    b.add(new Bar());

    n.add(new Nar());
    n.add(new Nar());
    n.add(new Nar());


    //prints FOO
    List<Foo> foo = g.copyList(l);

    //prints BAR
    List<Bar> bar = gb.copyList(b);

    //prints FOO
    List<Nar> nar = gn.copyList(n);

    /* Is there a clean way to prevent a typecast of Foo to Nar using generics*/

    }

}

class Foo implements WantToClone{
    public Foo(){}
    private Foo(int i){
    System.out.println("Foo");
    }
    public Foo instance(){
    return new Foo(1);
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo{
    public Bar(){} 

    private Bar(int i){
    System.out.println("Bar");
    }
    public Bar instance(){
    return new Bar(1);
    }
}

class Nar extends Foo{
    public Nar(){} 

}

interface WantToClone<E extends WantToClone<E>>{
    public E instance();
}


class GenericCopyClass<S extends WantToClone>{

    public GenericCopyClass(){}

    public List<S> copyList(List<S> original){
        List<S> temp = new ArrayList<S>();

        for(S item : original){
            temp.add((S)item.instance());   
        }
        return original;
    }

}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Hello, World
Foo
Foo
Foo
Bar
Bar
Bar
Foo
Foo
Foo
```

*edit 1

Problems:

implicit type cast:

`temp.add((S)item.instance());`

interface does not explicitly specify the class instance:

`interface WantToClone<E extends WantToClone<E>>`

Comment: "sub-classes not inheriting interface X". But they all inherit X. Can you show in the code exactly what you are trying to solve.

Comment: ' temp.add((S)item.instance()); '  in the GenericCopyClass

Comment: Subclasses `extend` the super class, thus inherit all interfaces and non-private methods of the super class. So I'm not sure what you mean by "unsafe operations for sub-classes not inheriting interface 'X'", since all subclasses inherit interface X, including the implementation in `Foo`.

Comment: The unsafe operation is that the `Nar` class does not contain a `instance` method, thus the `GenericCopyClass` must call the inherited interface method for `Foo` which results in a typecast copy of `(Nar)('class Foo copy')`. This is dangerous since Foo does not contain any specializations of `Nar`, yet we have a list of `Nar` objects of type `Foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with parametrized abstract class that will contain all common method and let sub classes implement only `instance` method:

```
    public abstract class AbstractFoo< F extends AbstractFoo<F> > 
    implements WantToClone<F>{

        public AbstractFoo(){}

        //add common methods here
    }

    public class Foo extends AbstractFoo<Foo>{
        public Foo(){}

        private Foo(int i){
            System.out.println("Foo");
        }

        public Foo instance(){
            return new Foo(1);
        }
    }

    public class Bar extends AbstractFoo<Bar>{
        public Bar(){} 

        private Bar(int i){
            System.out.println("Bar");
        }

        public Bar instance(){
            return new Bar(1);
        }
    }

    public class Nar extends AbstractFoo<Nar>{
        public Nar(){}

        @Override
        public Nar instance() {
            return new Nar();
        } 

    }

    public interface WantToClone< E extends WantToClone<E> >{
        public E instance();
    }


    public class GenericCopyClass< S extends WantToClone<S> >{

        public GenericCopyClass(){}

        public List<S> copyList(List<S> original){
            List<S> temp = new ArrayList<S>();

            for(S item : original){
                temp.add( item.instance() );   
            }
            return original;
        }    
    }
```

Comment: This is a good solution since it forces the user to implement the interface, and restricts creation of any classes with improper Types. However, by doing so no other classes can inherit instances 'Nar' or 'Bar'... I would be interested in a solution which throws an error at compile time on a class which is accessing the subclass method signature 'instance' which the subclass does not contain, but the parent does.  However, I think this violates the principle of inheritance. Thanks for the answer thou.

Comment: The problem you are facing is that inheritance does not work the way you are expecting. There is nothing that will prevent you from calling `instance` on `Nar` class. Once you define a method on super class/interface all subclasses will have that method.